# Apply the same calculation in different data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to loop over many data frames in R and I feel like this is a rather basic question. However, I only found similar questions that were solved with specific functions that don't match my problem (like calculating means or medians, changing column names, ...). I hope to find a more general solution that can be applied for any change or calculation in various data frames here.

I have a lot (about 500) of data frames that look somewhat like this (very simplified):

```
df0100
    a   b   c   d
1   4   3   5  NA
2   2   5   4  NA
3   4   4   3  NA
...

df0130
    a   b   c   d
1   3   2   3  NA
2   4   5   3  NA
3   4   3   2  NA
...
```

For each of them, I want to calculate a new value (also simplified here) from the values in a and c in the first row and insert the value in any row in column d. It works fine like this for a single data frame:

```
df0100$d <- ((df0100[1,1]*(df0100[1,3]+13.5)/(3*exp(df0100[1,3]))/100
```

which leads to

```
df0100
   a   b   c          d
1  4   3   5   36.60858
2  2   5   4   36.60858
3  4   4   3   36.60858
....
```

Since I don't want to do this for every single of the 500 data frames, I saved them as a list and tried to loop over them as follows.  I thought the easiest way would be to replace the former 'df0100' by each data frame name but both versions didn't work. Can anyone tell me what I have to change?

```
my_files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
my_data <- lapply(my_files, read.csv)
```

Version 1:

```
for (n in my_data)
{
   n$d <- ((n[1,1]*(n[1,3]+13.5)/(3*exp(n[1,3]))/100
}
```

Version 2:

```
my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(n){
   n$d <- ((n[1,1]*(n[1,3]+13.5)/(3*exp(n[1,3]))/100
})
```

This is my first question here, I hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: In your `lapply` after computing `n$d <- etc` include `n` or `return(n)` (they're equivalent) in the next line. This will return the changed value, which you are forgetting to do.

Comment: Wow, that was quick and it worked, thank you so much!